# Fortify360 with an automated build process?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, build-automation, fortify

Anyone have any sample configurations using CruiseControl.net or similar tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is:

1. Install Microsoft Visual Studio on the build server
2. Install Fortify SCA on the build server
3. In the cruise control configuration, check out the source code
4. Specify the cruise control configuation to run the following in a Visual Studio command prompt:

   sourceanalyzer -b FOO devenv solution.sln /REBUILD "Debug"

The final parameter is the name of the build configuration; this configuration needs to emit PDBs for any buildable component you need SCA to analyze.

Comment: thanks. I really wanted to avoid having to install VS on the build server... another handy "script" here allows to automatically upload the resulting fpr file : "C:\pathTO\fortifyclient.bat" -url http://f360/ -authtoken TOKEN uploadFPR -file "C:\results.fpr" -projectID XYZ

Comment: Note to @DouglasHeld also that `sourceanalyzer -b FOO devenv solution.sln /REBUILD /Release` seems to work fine -- noting that my projects emit PDBs on Release builds.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't already found it, you can get the authtoken from:
fortifyclient token -gettoken AnalysisUploadToken -url [url] -user [YourUsername]

For uploads, I find it easier to use the string arguments of both "-project [PROJECT] -version [VERSION]" instead of the -projectID [NUMBER]. Same thing, different invocation.

Comment: A question to @Costlow about the -gettoken command.

Is this a permanent token?  If your LDAP/Active-Directory password happens to change...must you renew your token?  Is it good across separate Windows Login sessions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Permanent: no, it is defined with a maximum validity of 90 days.

Comment: Password change: I do not know.

Comment: Validity across sessions: This doesn't mean anything; it is an authentication token and is not related to any single session.  You can think of the token as providing the equivalent of a username and password, for a restricted set of operations, and for a restricted time.